# Dynamic users (from Curl XML) CIDR not merged to ACL (Freeswitch)

Tags: freeswitch

Does anybody know how should looks like the answer (from web server) in case i do reloadacl and have xml_curl module enabled at Freeswitch? I see the request from FS but I do not see any example about shape of answer. I need to load users with cidrs to FS. It works very good with xml directory (FS create acl list automatically) but I have users in databases.

I think the respond probably should contain users with cidrs, but what is the format.